# Создание релиза в c++ win form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делаю релиз своей программы, выставляя во вкладке releas, и при запуске весь функционал работает , но когда запускаю exe файл, который находится в папке с релизом, то некоторые кнопки не работают! Проделываю одинаковые операции!!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скриншоты в студию

Comment: прикрепил, надеюсь вы меня поняли) Второй запуск в вс, так должно быть, первый ехе